# Barabasi-Albert graph algorithm

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using this algorithm to generate Barabási-Albert graphs. My objective using the code like this, instead of using the Built-in function, because I'll add some modifications further, in the mechanism of the new node creation.

```
barabasi[n_, m_] /; n >= 3 := 
 Module[{g, vdeg, el, el2, node, newnode}, 
  g = ConstantArray[{}, n];
  g[[1 ;; m + 1]] = Table[Delete[Range[m + 1], j], {j, m + 1}];
  vdeg = ConstantArray[0, n];
  vdeg[[1 ;; m + 1]] = m;
  Do[
   node = RandomSample[vdeg[[1 ;; j - 1]] -> Range[j - 1], m];
   g[[j]] = node;
   vdeg[[j]] = m;
   Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1; g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, node}]
   , {j, m + 2, n}];
  Graph[Union[
    Map[Sort, Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &, g], 1]]]]]
```

In the documentation I found that the algorithm starts with a 'CompleteGraph', which corresponds to the first part of the code:

```
g = ConstantArray[{}, n];
g[[1 ;; m + 1]] = Table[Delete[Range[m + 1], j], {j, m + 1}];
vdeg = ConstantArray[0, n];
vdeg[[1 ;; m + 1]] = m;
```

In some papers the model is said to start with a 'CycleGraph' instead of 'CompleteGraph', and I'm trying to adapt this code to this, and see if I have the same results. I do not know it would be possible to write something to generate the 'CycleGraph' using a structure similar to the one above.

One way I found to generate the 'CycleGraph' is this one:

```
cyclegraph[n_,m_] /; n>=3 :=
Module[{g},
g = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 \[Or] Abs[i - j] == m -> 
  1, {m+1, m+1}]
```

But I'm not sure if this is efficient to use it, since to generate the 'VertexDegree' list I'll have to make the graph at every step inside the 'Do' loop.

Comment: Why don't you use AdjacencyMatrix[CycleGraph[n]] ?

Comment: @halmir I thought about using it, but the problem is that it will take a lot of time to generate the new network, since every step inside the 'Do' loop I'll have to generate a graph in order to have its vertex degree and add the new node.

Comment: It's indeed efficient than your function.

Comment: Take a look at `IGBarabasiAlbertGame` in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).  It has many more customization options than the built-in version, so perhaps it'll suit your needs.